# Integrating Spring dependency injection with Ninja framework

Tags: java, spring, ninjaframework

I have recently looked into replacing our current java web framework (Play framework) into a more java based framework. I have came across two web frameworks that looked attractive to me: [The Ninja Framework](http://www.ninjaframework.org/) & Spark Framework.

I tend to prefer the Ninja Framework, but I can not manage to find a working example of it along with [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)'s dependency injection container (That I currently use with no intentions to replace it).

Can anyone point me to a working example (of Spring with Ninja) or describe some pros or cons about using the Ninja Framework?

Comment: Looking at Ninja documentation it explicitly says it uses Google Guice [Ninja Dependency Injection](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/basic_concepts/dependency_injection.html) section. It does not make sense to add new DI container to the mix.

Comment: Yes I am aware to that use, and my will is to change the DI provider from guice to spring, because I currently use it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't replace it with spring boot, however guice is highly capable DI container, I actually prefer it to spring boot, it is more similar to other framework DI not just java based ones. In general ninja is a great framework, yes one of the downsides it isn't the easiest to swap out things like DI containers or html templates. This is also something I would like to see improved. Other than that it is a great framework!

Comment: Thanks man, I'm well aware of it by now, and decided to go with Spring boot. Couldn't be more satisfied by my decision, and would recommend it to anyone.

Comment: Yes, spring boot has a great community as well which something ninja lacks. Good choice!